# Unable to put api and personal input into one object array and my datamap.map cant be render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    FormControl,
    Form,
    InputGroup,
    Button,
    Container,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as usertz from 'user-timezone';

const AxieAPI = () => {
    const [dataAll, setDataAll] = useState([
        {
            id: '',
            myName: '',
            roninAddress: '',
            walletData: {
                adventureSLP: '',
                calendar: {
                    delta: '',
                    todaySLP: '',
                    yesterdayDelta: '',
                    yesterdaySLP: '',
                },
                claim_timestamp: '',
                ingame_slp: '',
                last_claim_amount: '',
                lastupdate: '',
                next_claim_timestamp: '',
                pvpData: {
                    elo: '',
                    rank: '',
                },
                ronin_slp: '',
                total_slp: '',
            },
        },
    ]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dataAll);
}, [dataAll]);

const userAddress = dataAll.roninAddress;

var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://axie-infinity.p.rapidapi.com/get-final-data/0x${userAddress}`,
    params: { id: `0x${userAddress}` },
    headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': process.env.REACT_APP_HOST,
        'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_KEY,
    },
};

const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    // setRoninAddress(e.target.value.substring(6));
    e.preventDefault();
    const fieldName = e.target.getAttribute('name');
    const fieldValue = e.target.value;
    const newFormData = { ...dataAll };
    newFormData[fieldName] = fieldValue;
};

const onSubmitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios
        .request(options)
        .then(function (response) {
            const newUser = {
                id: nanoid(),
                myName: dataAll.name,
                roninAddress: dataAll.roninAddress,
            };
            let arr = response.data;
            const newUsers = [...dataAll, newUser, arr];
            setDataAll(newUsers);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });

    console.log(dataAll);
};

return (
    <div>
        <Container className="p-5">
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                <FormControl
                    aria-label="Small"
                    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                    name="myName"
                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                />

                <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                    <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">ronin:</InputGroup.Text>
                    <FormControl
                        aria-label="Small"
                        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                        // value={roninAddress}
                        name="roninAddress"
                        onChange={onChangeHandler}
                    />
                    <Button type="submit">Add User</Button>
                </InputGroup>
            </Form>

            <div>
                {/* <p>Last Claim Amount : {data.walletData.last_claim_amount}</p>
            <p>Yesterday Earn SLP: {data.walletData.calendar.yesterdaySLP}</p>
            <p>Total SLP : {data.walletData.total_slp}</p>
            <p>Today Adv SLP ?/50: {data.walletData.adventureSLP}</p>
            <p>Rank : {data.walletData.pvpData.rank}</p>
            <p>MMR : {data.walletData.pvpData.elo}</p>
            <p>Next Claim : {datetime}</p> */}

                {/* {dataAll.map((singleData) => {
                    const unixTimeStamp = singleData.walletData.next_claim_timestamp;
                    const dateTimeFormat = 'MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm ss A';
                    const datetime = usertz.datetime(unixTimeStamp, dateTimeFormat);

                    return (
                        <div>
                            <p>User Name : {singleData.name}</p>
                            <p>
                                Last Claim Amount : {singleData.walletData.last_claim_amount}
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Yesterday Earn SLP:{' '}
                                {singleData.walletData.calendar.yesterdaySLP}
                            </p>
                            <p>Total SLP : {singleData.walletData.total_slp}</p>
                            <p>Today Adv SLP ?/50: {singleData.walletData.adventureSLP}</p>
                            <p>Rank : {singleData.walletData.pvpData.rank}</p>
                            <p>MMR : {singleData.walletData.pvpData.elo}</p>
                            <p>Next Claim : {datetime}</p>
                        </div>
                    );
                })} */}
                 {dataAll.slice(1).map((data) => {
                    return <p key="{item}">User Name : {data.name}</p>;
                })} 
            </div>
        </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AxieAPI;
```

[image]

I can't save it all into one state under dataAll with API + own input (name and address) when console.log it came out to be separated  + I cant render the allData.map it loads as map not function. The spread operator seems got error as well. Sry this project is my first time start from scratch with what i know so far
the key for above code for .env is from
https://rapidapi.com/jchbasco/api/axie-infinity

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    FormControl,
    Form,
    InputGroup,
    Button,
    Container,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as usertz from 'user-timezone';

const AxieAPI = () => {
    const [dataAll, setDataAll] = useState([
        {
            id: '',
            myName: '',
            roninAddress: '',
            walletData: {
                adventureSLP: '',
                calendar: {
                    delta: '',
                    todaySLP: '',
                    yesterdayDelta: '',
                    yesterdaySLP: '',
                },
                claim_timestamp: '',
                ingame_slp: '',
                last_claim_amount: '',
                lastupdate: '',
                next_claim_timestamp: '',
                pvpData: {
                    elo: '',
                    rank: '',
                },
                ronin_slp: '',
                total_slp: '',
            },
        },
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(dataAll);
    }, [dataAll]);

    const userAddress = dataAll.roninAddress;

    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://axie-infinity.p.rapidapi.com/get-final-data/0x${userAddress}`,
        params: { id: `0x${userAddress}` },
        headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-host': process.env.REACT_APP_HOST,
            'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_KEY,
        },
    };

    const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        // setRoninAddress(e.target.value.substring(6));
        e.preventDefault();
        const fieldName = e.target.getAttribute('name');
        const fieldValue = e.target.value;
        const newFormData = { ...dataAll };
        newFormData[fieldName] = fieldValue;
        setDataAll(newFormData);
    };

    const onSubmitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        await axios
            .request(options)
            .then(function (response) {
                const newUser = {
                    id: nanoid(),
                    myName: dataAll.myName,
                    roninAddress: dataAll.roninAddress,
                    data: response.data,
                };

                const newUsers = [newUser];
                setDataAll(newUsers);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });

        console.log(dataAll);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Container className="p-5">
                <Form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                    <FormControl
                        aria-label="Small"
                        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                        name="myName"
                        onChange={onChangeHandler}
                    />

                    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1">ronin:</InputGroup.Text>
                        <FormControl
                            aria-label="Small"
                            aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                            // value={roninAddress}
                            name="roninAddress"
                            onChange={onChangeHandler}
                        />
                        <Button type="submit">Add User</Button>
                    </InputGroup>
                </Form>

                <div>
                    {/* <p>Last Claim Amount : {data.walletData.last_claim_amount}</p>
                <p>Yesterday Earn SLP: {data.walletData.calendar.yesterdaySLP}</p>
                <p>Total SLP : {data.walletData.total_slp}</p>
                <p>Today Adv SLP ?/50: {data.walletData.adventureSLP}</p>
                <p>Rank : {data.walletData.pvpData.rank}</p>
                <p>MMR : {data.walletData.pvpData.elo}</p>
                <p>Next Claim : {datetime}</p> */}

                    {/* {dataAll.map((singleData) => {
                        const unixTimeStamp = singleData.walletData.next_claim_timestamp;
                        const dateTimeFormat = 'MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm ss A';
                        const datetime = usertz.datetime(unixTimeStamp, dateTimeFormat);

                        return (
                            <div>
                                <p>User Name : {singleData.name}</p>
                                <p>
                                    Last Claim Amount : {singleData.walletData.last_claim_amount}
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Yesterday Earn SLP:{' '}
                                    {singleData.walletData.calendar.yesterdaySLP}
                                </p>
                                <p>Total SLP : {singleData.walletData.total_slp}</p>
                                <p>Today Adv SLP ?/50: {singleData.walletData.adventureSLP}</p>
                                <p>Rank : {singleData.walletData.pvpData.rank}</p>
                                <p>MMR : {singleData.walletData.pvpData.elo}</p>
                                <p>Next Claim : {datetime}</p>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })} */}
                    {dataAll.map((data) => {
                        return <p key="{item}">User Name : {data.name}</p>;
                    })}
                </div>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AxieAPI;
```

I was manage to merge the data into one state (only now I'm stuck at the object.map get error.
[image]

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    FormControl,
    Form,
    Button,
    Container,
    Card,
    Row,
    Col,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as usertz from 'user-timezone';
import './card.css';
import slp from '../assets/SLP.png';
import ronin from '../assets/ronin.png';

const AxieAPI = () => {
    const [price, setPrice] = useState([{ current_price: '' }]);
    const [addFormData, setAddFormData] = useState({
        myName: '',
        roninAddress: '',
        manager: '',
        scholar: '',
    });
    const [dataAll, setDataAll] = useState([
        {
            id: '0',
            myName: '',
            manager: '',
            scholar: '',
            roninAddress: '',
            priceResult: '',
            data: {
                walletData: {
                    adventureSLP: '',
                    calendar: {
                        delta: '',
                        todaySLP: '',
                        yesterdayDelta: '',
                        yesterdaySLP: '',
                    },
                    claim_timestamp: '',
                    ingame_slp: '',
                    last_claim_amount: '',
                    lastupdate: '',
                    next_claim_timestamp: '',
                    pvpData: {
                        elo: '',
                        rank: '',
                    },
                    ronin_slp: '',
                    total_slp: '',
                },
            },
        },
    ]);

    const baseURL =
        'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=smooth-love-potion&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false';

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            await axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line
                response.data.map((pri) => {
                    const answer = pri.current_price;
                    setPrice(answer);
                });
            });
        }
        fetchData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [dataAll]);

    const userAddress = addFormData.roninAddress.slice(6);

    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://axie-infinity.p.rapidapi.com/get-final-data/0x${userAddress}`,
        params: { id: `0x${userAddress}` },
        headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-host': process.env.REACT_APP_HOST,
            'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_KEY,
        },
    };

    const onChangeHandler = async (e) => {
        // setRoninAddress(e.target.value);
        await e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const fieldName = e.target.getAttribute('name');
            const fieldValue = e.target.value;
            const newFormData = { ...addFormData };
            newFormData[fieldName] = fieldValue;
            setAddFormData(newFormData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    const onSubmitHandler = async (e) => {
        await e.preventDefault();

        await axios
            .request(options)
            .then(function (response) {
                const newUser = {
                    id: nanoid(),
                    myName: addFormData.myName,
                    roninAddress: addFormData.roninAddress,
                    manager: addFormData.manager,
                    scholar: addFormData.scholar,
                    data: response.data,
                };
                const newUsers = [...dataAll, newUser];
                setDataAll(newUsers);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
        e.target.reset();
        console.log(dataAll);
    };

    let totalSLP = dataAll.slice(1).reduce(async function (accumulator, item) {
        try {
            return accumulator + item.data.walletData.total_slp;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, 0);

    console.log(totalSLP);

    return (
        <div>
            <Container className="p-4">
                <Form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={12} lg={6}>
                            <Form.Label>Scholar Name</Form.Label>
                            <FormControl
                                aria-label="Small"
                                aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                                name="myName"
                                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={12} lg={6}>
                            <Form.Label>Ronin Address</Form.Label>
                            <FormControl
                                aria-label="Small"
                                aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                                // value={roninAddress}
                                placeholder="ronin:12345-54321"
                                name="roninAddress"
                                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={12} lg={6}>
                            <Form.Label>Manager %</Form.Label>

                            <FormControl
                                aria-label="Small"
                                aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                                name="manager"
                                type="number"
                                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={12} lg={6}>
                            <Form.Label>Scholar %</Form.Label>
                            <FormControl
                                aria-label="Small"
                                aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                                name="scholar"
                                type="number"
                                onChange={onChangeHandler}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Row>

                    <div className="d-grid gap-2 pt-3">
                        <Button type="submit" size="lg">
                            Add User
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </Form>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        {dataAll.slice(1).map((singleData) => {
                            const unixTimeStamp =
                                singleData.data.walletData.next_claim_timestamp;
                            const dateTimeFormat = 'MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm ss A';
                            const datetime = usertz.datetime(unixTimeStamp, dateTimeFormat);
                            const totalslp = singleData.data.walletData.total_slp;
                            const scholar = singleData.scholar;
                            const manager = singleData.manager;
                            const answerScholar = (totalslp * scholar) / 100;
                            const answerManager = (totalslp * manager) / 100;
                            const totalusdslp = price * totalslp;
                            const newtotalusdslp = totalusdslp.toFixed(2);
                            const managerusd = price * answerManager;
                            const newmanagerusd = managerusd.toFixed(2);
                            const scholarusd = price * answerScholar;
                            const newscholarusd = scholarusd.toFixed(2);

                            return (
                                <Card
                                    style={{
                                        width: '21rem',
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.105)',
                                        borderRadius: '15px',
                                    }}
                                    className="main-css m-1 mt-5"
                                    as={Col}
                                    lg={4}
                                    key={singleData.id}
                                >
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Card.Title>
                                            <h3 className="py-3">{singleData.myName}</h3>
                                        </Card.Title>
                                        <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-truncate">
                                            <img src={ronin} alt="ronin" height="30px" />{' '}
                                            {singleData.roninAddress}
                                        </Card.Subtitle>
                                        <Card.Text
                                            style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                            className="text-justify text-center"
                                        >
                                             Last SLP Claim -{' '}
                                            {singleData.data.walletData.last_claim_amount}
                                            <img src={slp} alt="slp" height="20px" />{' '}
                                        </Card.Text>
                                        <div
                                            className="bg-secondary p-3 text-white text-center"
                                            style={{ borderRadius: '10px' }}
                                        >
                                            <Card.Text>
                                                ‍ Manager: {answerManager}
                                                <img src={slp} alt="slp" height="20px" />
                                                <br /> $ USD {newmanagerusd}
                                            </Card.Text>
                                            <hr />
                                            <Card.Text>
                                                 Scholar: {answerScholar}
                                                <img src={slp} alt="slp" height="20px" />
                                                <br /> $ USD {newscholarusd}
                                            </Card.Text>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="py-3 text-center">
                                            <h3>
                                                <img src={slp} alt="slp" height="35px" />
                                                {singleData.data.walletData.total_slp} SLP <br />
                                            </h3>
                                            <p>$ USD {newtotalusdslp}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <Card.Text className="text-center">
                                            Yesterday :{' '}
                                            {singleData.data.walletData.calendar.yesterdayDelta}
                                            <img src={slp} alt="slp" height="20px" />
                                            <br />
                                            Today : {singleData.data.walletData.calendar.delta}
                                            <img src={slp} alt="slp" height="20px" />
                                        </Card.Text>
                                        <hr />
                                         Next Claim
                                        <br />
                                        {datetime}
                                        <Row>
                                            <Card.Text as={Col} className="text-warning">
                                                ⚔️MMR {singleData.data.walletData.pvpData.elo}
                                            </Card.Text>
                                            <Card.Text as={Col} className="text-warning">
                                                Rank {singleData.data.walletData.pvpData.rank}
                                            </Card.Text>
                                        </Row>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </Card>
                            );
                        })}
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AxieAPI;
```

This is the latest I have made with above fix but still have some async for the {singleData.data.walletData.last_claim_amount} sometime still return error sometime not